# blade template doesn't work inside another blade template

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this file which contains this code:

```
<x-layout>
    <x-container>
        <x-form>
            <x-input type="text" id="text1"/>
             <x-input type="number" id="number1"/>
        </x-form> 
    </x-container>
</x-layout>
```

For some reason, the template **form** doesn't work INSIDE the **container**, but if I put it like this, it works fine:

```
<x-layout>
    <x-container>
    
    </x-container>

<x-form>
        <x-input type="text" id="text1"/>
        <x-input type="number" id="number1"/>
    </x-form> 
     
</x-layout>
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: could you share your `container.blade.php` ?

Comment: You might forgot to add `{{ $slot }}` to `container.blade.php`

Comment: exactly, that was it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply the variable `{{$slot}}` *(which is inside the form template)* to the container so it can know where to put the actual form.